# NSdateFormatter in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am beginner in ios development.
I am stuck in NSdateFormatter class.
My question is:

Which kind of formatter support on this date "Oct, 25th"?

Please help me,
Thanks in advance...

Comment: This will not work for "Oct, 1st" and "Oct, 2nd"

Answer (score 1):

you can format date by  "Oct, 25" you must append "th" with the formatted date

Answer (score 0):

```
 [yourDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LLL,dd'th'"];
```

LLL: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

dd: 01~31 ( Day of Month)

for more info about date-formate see my blog from this link..

[MyBlog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html)

**For Example**

call this method with bellow 2 line code..

```
NSString *strDate = [self StringFromDate:@"Oct, 25th"];
NSLog(@"\n New Date is HERE  =====>> %@",strDate);
```

this is the method just paste in your `.m` file

```
-(NSString *)StringFromDate:(NSString *)DateLocal{
    //    DateLocal = [self trimString:DateLocal];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];   
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LLL,dd'th'"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: DateLocal];
    NSString *tt = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSDate *dateReturn = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tt];


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd,LLL"];// set the format which you want
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateReturn];  
    NSLog(@"Date is HERE  =====>> %@",dateString);
    [dateFormat release];
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: @RaviM i edit the code dude with this format @"LLL,dd'th'" try this and tell me its working or not mate...

Answer (score 0):

I would like te stress you not to use explicit date formats, since if the users setting is not set to english the date might not be presented correctly.

Instead you should use the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties of [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

See Apple [`NSDateFormatterStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW2) documentation to see which one will work for you.